# How to dispatch other thunk request on succession of a redux thunk request in react-redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using react-redux toolkit with redux thunk to make the api calls. In my app, when I dispatch a thunk for update or delete request and after it succession I want to call the get request as well but only way I was able to figure out is by using a flag with useEffect. Is there any better approach you guys can share?

I also tried this piece in my slice file but it won't work as useDispatch cannot be called inside a javascript function block

```
.addCase(propertiesThunk.deleteProperty.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => (
      useDispatch(propertiesThunk.getProperties())
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems here.

The first is that you can *never* call a React hook outside of a function component, so you definitely can't call `useDispatch` inside of a reducer.

The second problem is that [a reducer can never have side effects](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects).  That means it can *never* dispatch actions.  A reducer is *only* for returning an updated state value.

The simplest answer here would be to have an event handler that does both of these steps back-to-back:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleClick = async () => {
    await dispatch(someAsyncThunk())
    dispatch(someOtherActionHere())
    // or some request, or...
  }
}
```

Another option would be to use the new RTK "listener" side effects middleware, and kick off more logic when some action is dispatched:

```js
startListening({
  actionCreator: someAsyncThunk.fulfilled,
  effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
    // do more work here
  }
})
```

See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware for details.